# How to get last years qty in measure

Tags: ssas

How can I create a measure that has previous years Qty SHipped by month that will be used against a Current year measure showing a variance?

I want to take last years qty shipped minus the Plan(I already have this measure working) to get a variance. I have a dimension called dates that has a YY.

example calc..

[Measure].[pyqty] - [Measure].[Plan]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May help you something like this:
It calculates the QTD of the parallel previous period

```
  WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Current QTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      QTD([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]
    ) 
     MEMBER [Measures].[Last QTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      YTD
      (
        ParallelPeriod
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]
         ,1
         ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]
    ) 
    select {[Measures].[Current QTD],[Measures].[Last QTD]} ON 0 
    FROM [Adventure Works]
    WHERE [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[11]
```

Take a o look at [Time Calculations](http://www.obs3.com/pdf/A%20Different%20Approach%20to%20Time%20Calculations%20in%20SSAS.pdf), in order to add time intelligence to your cube